# XML Plugin not working with SonarQube 4.5.2

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

According to the sonarqube website, the XML plugin is supported for sonarqube 4.5.2, although upon trying to activate this plugin in the sonar application (via the manual way of copying the jar into ./extensions/plugins) it causes the sonar application to fail to start after running sonar.sh. I'm unable to install the plugin via the update center since I'm running a sonar locally using the embedded database.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/XML+Plugin

Either the XML Plugin is incorrectly stated as being able to support 4.5.2 or there is a problem on my side.

If someone on the sonar team could clarify this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in your server log? Also, using the embedded database should not prevent you from using the Update Center.

Comment: From the server startup log file:

2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins...
2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Core / 4.5.2 / 0
2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 4.5.2 / 0
2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.4 / a334be36ba4374bb779255272c53fb08675ac2c2
2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Java / 2.4 / 7e7e6335211bb9c0ff9727065f43e7010cc3df91

Comment: 2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin XML / 1.4 / eabc7d2152576a7229cf42c312ddb4a194c6b06d
2016.01.15 10:05:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase]  Embedded database stopped
2016.01.15 10:05:48 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Plugin xml needs a more recent version of SonarQube than 4.5.2. At least 4.5.4 is expected

Comment: add them to the question

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the stated compatibility in the update center, that has been corrected. For SonarQube platform 4.5.2, there is not a compatible version of the XML plugin. You would need to upgrade to 4.5.4.